# MOD URL REWRITE help .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, rule

Please somebody help me to get url mod rewrite like following.
My url is `mydomain.com/music/album.php?id=1234&title=sometext&page=2&lang=en`

I want this url like following

```
mydomain.com/music/1234/sometext/?page=2&lage=en
```

UPDATE:
Mypage:
mydomain.com/cms/album.php?id=12493&album=text-to-show

I have rewritten this url to

RewriteRule ^music/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ /cms/album.php?id=$1&album=$2 [L]

My MODDED URL: mydomain.com/music/12493/text-to-show.html

---

Problem:
My album.php has more $_GET variable which i want to handle them like a normal script.
like mydomain.com/music/12493/text-to-show.html?page=1
should act on server as 
mydomain.com/cms/album.php?id=12493&album=text-to-show&page=1

Note: i can rewrite like mydomain.com/music/12493/text-to-show/2.html
but this is not which i am looking for.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet without checking for integer / string, you can use this but it is adised to rewrite it to your needs.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /music/album.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I tried it but its not working. i want extra pera meter without rewriting url. Few portion of url will be rewritten and rest of url i want to handle like normal url with additional perameter. mydomain.com/music/1234/sometext/?extraParam=extravalue&extraParam2=ExtraValue2